# AjaxControlToolKit 3.02 to 16.1 Migration - ScriptObjectBuilder not available

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

We are migrating AjaxControlToolKit 3.02 to 16.1 used in a ASP.NET project.We have following code snippet in the existing 3.02 version:

```
AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptObjectBuilder.GetScriptReferences()
```

While AjaxControlToolKit version is updated to 16.1 the above code snippet is not complied due to unavailability of the  *ScriptObjectBuilder* class and *GetScriptReferences* method. It seems the class is deprecated in the higer version of the library.

In that case, how the above code can be re-written to achieve the same functionality?

Any approach or suggestion would help us.

Comment: Hi. I gave some info, but it seems we need more context to figure out how this code can be rewritten. Would you please update your answer with more details about the purpose of this method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no direct analogue to this method.
The [`ToolkitResourceManager` class](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit/ToolkitResourceManager.cs) is a successor of the `ScriptObjectBuilder` and has many methods for registering resources.

Foe example, it has [`GetControlScriptReferences(Type type)`](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit/ToolkitResourceManager.cs#L60-L66) method. It calls [`GetEmbeddedScripts(params string[] toolkitBundles)` internally](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit/ToolkitResourceManager.cs#L68-L88), which is private now.